# Invoking a Console EXE from Powershell - Console.EXE app.config not being used

Tags: powershell

Running Powershell on Windows 2008 R2.

I've got a .NET console application which picks up a connection string from a configuration file and that all works fine when running the application directly.

Running via a Powershell script the application attempts to read the connection string from the configuration file and I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the following line...

```
 var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
```

I'm using the "&" in Powershell to run the executable.

A newbie to all this PowerShell stuff so praying it's something obvious and easy to rectify! :):)

Thx

Comment: When you say directly, do you mean double-clicking it or you run it via cmd.exe?  From PowerShell, what happens is you run it like this `cmd.exe /c path_to_exe`?

Comment: FYI PowerShell is a .NET process so it has its own app.config file.  This would explain your error if you were attempting to read the connection string in PowerShell script.  But it looks you're just attempting to run a .NET exe.  In that scnenario, the .NET loader should pick up the exe's app.config from the dir where the exe is located.

Comment: @Keith Hill - Apologies, when I say I ran t directly, what I should have said that I was running it from VS2010:( If I run it from a command prompt I get the same error. ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath returns the path of the configuration file I was expecting it to. However if I iterate of ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings i can't see a connection string with the required name I just get one pointing at aspnetdb.mdf.

Comment: @Keith Hill 0 Had a misnamed configuration file:(:(:( Thanks for taking the time to respond.